# Using SGML Reader to close single HTML tags

Tags: sgmlreader

I am using SgmlReader to generate XHTML output from HTML. The question is regarding single HTML tags like

`<IMG>`

When using SgmlReader, this tag is generated as

`<IMG></IMG>`

I know that this is syntactically correct, however, for XHTML style, I need to know if it is possible to generate

`<IMG />`

instead.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify DocType property, like this one:

```
Sgml.SgmlReader sgmlReader = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML";
```

Also you should have ["Html.dtd"](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader/blob/master/SgmlReader/Html.dtd) file in embedded resources of SgmlReader project.
It helped me.